# Normaliztion in linear regression (gradient descent)

Tags: python, machine-learning, overflow, linear-regression, gradient-descent

I am writing a simple (gradient descent) code for linear regression with multi variables data set, my problem was that when I was testing the code I noticed that the cost still decreasing after 5 million iterations which means that my learning rate is small, I tried to increase it but I got overflow for the cost value, then when I normalized the data the problem had been solved and I could increase my learning rate without getting any error, I was wondering what is the relation between normalization and overflow for the cost.

[gradient descent without normalization (small learning rate)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QK10z.png)

[data without normalization (bigger learning rate)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mblbM.png)

[data normalized with big learning rate](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ySQvs.png)

[data before normaliztion](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kRW7f.png)
[data after normaliztion](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iyNKk.png)

Comment: Please do **not** post screenshots of code - see how to create a [mre].

Comment: And this is not a programming problem, this concept is covered in any basic neural networks course.

Comment: thanks for the advice, I'll try to improve my presentation of the questions.
I think I get the idea of how normalization help to make learning faster but I didn't get how undoing normalization causes overflow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically, normalization of the inputs gives the surface of the function you want to optimize a more spherical shape. Without this normalization, differences in the scale of the variables may cause the surface to be more ellipsoidal.

Now you could ask: why speherical vs. ellipsoidal matters?
As the gradient descent is a first derivative method it is not considering the curvature of the surface when choosing the direction before taking a step. Then, having an ellipsoidal surface (more irregular curvature) can cause trouble with convergence (this bringing overflow) specially if you set a large learning rate (the algorithm is taking bigger steps at each iteration). I think it is easier to understand by looking [2d plot example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VGB9L.png). With a spherical surface the gradient points at the minimum which makes learning easier.

Comment: thanks for your help, I think the idea is more clear for me now.